# How to correct "expression must have same data type as corresponding expression" error?

Tags: sql, oracle

For example I have table department and employee
I want to find the names of the employees together with budget of department employees belong to 
Inside employee table it contain employee name which is ename
department table it contain budget for department

The command that I used

```
SELECT ENAME FROM EMPLOYEE
UNION
SELECT BUDGET FROM DEPARTMENT
ORDER BY ENAME;
```

but I keep getting expression must have same data type as corresponding expression error

Can someone explain to me What is wrong with my concept and how to obtain the result .

Comment: is it `mysql` or `sqlserver`? You have tagged both.

Comment: I just googled the error message. It's oracle??

Comment: I guess UNION funda is similar across every RDBMS.

Comment: Sorry actually I am using Oracle Sql plus to run the program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says.  It looks as though ENAME is a string and BUDGET is a numeric.

It sounds like you want to return these two values in a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT ENAME, SUM(BUDGET) 
FROM EMPLOYEE INNER JOIN BUDGET
ON EMPLOYEE.ID = BUDGET.ID
GROUP BY ENAME
```

Note I'm making assumptions as to your data types, randomly throwing an ID out there, and assuming you want to sum the data.  Oh, and the platform.  The SQL should be pretty standard I guess, but this is T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess You're trying to union two tables which are having different datatype, and union requires datatype of both columns should be same.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

See the msdn says `The data types must be compatible.`